# How to find "index out of bound" if I don't get Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, c, arrays, segmentation-fault, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a program which cause Seg fault in a machine, which is not accessible for me. However, when I compile and run it with the same compiler and same input on my machine, I don't get anything. The problem is probably  "array index out of bound" which might lead to Seg Fault in some circumstances, however, compiler does not show any warning. The program is huge and complicated. So I cannot find the problem just by checking the code.

Any suggestion on how to get the Segmentation Fault on my machine too? This way I can debug the code and find the problem.

Comment: Have you tried breakpoint it? Modern IDE can break when there's an exception or crash, so you can traceback it.

Comment: have you try to debug your program? i.e by using `gdb`

Comment: I tried with gdb. I got no seg fault. Note that the problem is that the program finishes on my machine completely, with no error or seg fault. But I know there is a problem in the code which leads to seg fault in someone elses' machine.

Comment: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html, http://clang.llvm.org/docs/MemorySanitizer.html and http://valgrind.org are some of your best hopes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) if it works over Linux machine.
To use `valgrind` you just type on console:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --num-callers=20 --tool=memcheck ./program
```

and should return invalid read/write of size X according to the variable and (if you compiled with debugging information), it will tell you the line where the problem might be.

By the way, you can install `valgrind` in Ubuntu/Debian Linux (for example) just as easy as:

```
sudo apt-get install valgrind
```

Comment: While you can incrementally add options as needed to drill down on any specific error, simply running `valgrind ./program` will find all *invalid read/write of size X* issues related to your code. Compile your code with the options needed to generate a symbol table for debug info. With `gcc` that is `gcc -g ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can try a solution such as Valgrind as other posters mentioned, or your compiler may also have some specific ability to insert guard words before I located a raise to detect this kind of access.